# how to align instances to the normal of an object's face?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm currently trying to make a stitch generator, previously I had problems making the seams follow the path of the curve, but I managed to solve it with your help, thank you.

I'm currently in the final phase which would be: I need to make the seams always point in the direction of the normal of the face of an object, I tried the way shown in the print but I couldn't, I saw similar questions right here on the stack but I couldn't solve it , I would like help

[image]

[image: node tree]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! This question has been asked here several times. The node `Align Euler to Vector` is your friend here. If it is about the position, then the node `Raycast` will help you. Please use the search function. Apart from that, your blend file does not contain the example shown, but only the cube and a nurbs path, making the example redundant.

Comment: hello, I researched before, I tested the indicated modes but it didn't work for me :/, about the blend file, the print file is a working model in which I couldn't post, so I replaced it, im sorry